# Snakemake run rule with wildcarded output of previous rules multiple times

Tags: snakemake

I have multiple studies and I must make two files (a .notsad and .txt file) for each of the n number of  studies. After these are created, I must run a command which runs per chromosome and uses the same two input files (.notsad, .txt) for each chromosome within a given study. So:

```
mycommand.py study1.notsad study1_filter.txt chr1.bad.gz --out chr1_filter.bad.gz
mycommand.py study1.notsad study1_filter.txt chr2.bad.gz --out chr2_filter.bad.gz
...
mycommand.py study2.notsad study2_filter.txt chr1.bad.gz --out chr1_filter.bad.gz
...
```

However Im having trouble getting this to run. Im getting an error:

```
WildcardError in line 33 of /scripts/Snakefile:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'ds_lower'
```

My rules so far:

```
import os
import glob

ROOT = "/rootdir/"
ORIGINAL_DATA_FOLDER="original/"
PROCESS_DATA_FOLDER="process/"

ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE=ROOT+ORIGINAL_DATA_FOLDER
PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE=ROOT+PROCESS_DATA_FOLDER

DATASETS = [name for name in os.listdir(ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE, name))]
LOWERCASE_DATASETS = [dataset.lower() for dataset in DATASETS]
CHROMOSOME = list(range(1,23))

rule all:
    input:
        expand(PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/chr{chr}_filtered.gen.gz", ds=DATASETS, chr=CHROMOSOME)

rule run_command:
    input:
        ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/chr{chr}.bad.gz", # Matches 22 chroms
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/{ds_lower}_filter.txt", # But this should be common to all chr runs for this study.
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/{ds_lower}.notsad" # This one as well.
    output:
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/chr{chr}_filtered.gen.gz"
    shell:
        # Run command that uses each of the previous files and runs per chromosome
        "mycommand.py {input.2} {input.1} {input.0} --out {output}"

rule write_txt_file:
    input:
        ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/{ds_lower}_info.txt"
    output:
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/{ds_lower}_filter.txt"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"

rule write_notsad_file:
    input:
        ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/_{ds_lower}.sad"
    output:
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/{ds_lower}.notsad"
    shell:
        "touch {output}"
```

**UPDATE**
Changing inputs for rule `run_command` to lambda functions did work.

```
rule run_command:
    input:
        ORIGINAL_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/chr{chr}.gen.gz",
        lambda wildcards: PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE + f"{wildcards.ds}/{wildcards.ds.lower()}_filter.txt",
        lambda wildcards: PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE + f"{wildcards.ds}/{wildcards.ds.lower()}.sample"
    output:
        PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE+"{ds}/chr{chr}_filtered.gen.gz"
    run:
        # Run command that uses each of the previous files and runs per chromosome
        "mycommand.py {input.2} {input.1} {input.0} --out {output}"
```

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but your code would be "cleaner" if you used `os.path.join` instead of concatenating strings using "+" when you generate paths.

Comment: yes to @bli's suggestion. I use alternative library [`pathlib`](http://blog.danwin.com/using-python-3-pathlib-for-managing-filenames-and-directories/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the wildcards used in `input` need to be present in `output`. In rule `run_command`, wildcard `{ds_lower}` is present only in `input` but not in `output`.

Comment: Could you advise how to refactor these rules to accommodate what I'm trying to do?

Comment: @KBoehme I'm thinking you might do this by using functions as input to your rules. For instance, `lambda wildcards: PROCESS_DATA_SOURCE + f"{wildcards.ds}/{wildcards.ds.lower()}_filter.txt"` (using python 3.6+ "formatted string")

Comment: @bli Tried that and now snakemake can't resolve the input as the output of rule `write_txt_file`. It's feeling like its not possible in snakemake to handle this type of input.

Comment: @KBoehme Can you edit question to add what you tried?

Comment: @KBoehme you can use lambda functions to make it work